# Java swing searching arrayList & forms

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with several person objects. I am trying to ask the user to input the `employeeID` and then display it on a form. Can anyone help me please?

```
findByID = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String question = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the employees ID: ");
        boolean found;
        for(Person aPerson: personList) {
            if(aPerson.getEmployeeID().equalsIgnoreCase(question)) {
                displayDetails(currentItem);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("This Item doesnt exist");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

My code repeats the else statement no matter what the input is even if it matches a number saved in my ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

> My code repeats the else statement no matter what the input is even if it matches a number saved in my ArrayList.

Well sure, because that's what the code does. To do the `else` condition only if an item is not found, you need to decide whether it was found or not first. Right now it does it for every item that's not a match.

So basically you need to move the `else` so it's after the loop.

```
Person foundPerson = null;
for(Person aPerson : personList) {
    if(aPerson.getEmployeeID().equalsIgnoreCase(idToLookFor)) {
        foundPerson = aPerson;
        break;
    }
}

if(foundPerson != null) {
    /* do something with the person that was found */
} else {
    /* did not find the person */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not super clear on what you are asking, but you might want something like this:

```
findByID = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String question = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the employees ID: ");
        boolean found = false;
        for(Person aPerson: personList) {
            if(aPerson.getEmployeeID().equalsIgnoreCase(question)) {
                displayDetails(currentItem);
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("This Item doesnt exist");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Sorry for not being so clear. The solution for the forloop works great but I have JButtons first, last, previous and next which I have working fine but I have a JButton findById which I can't figure out. When I find my person I can't set currentItem to point to that person and display it